# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.people.map is not a function in react js while using the map function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import cardsDataset from "./cardsDataset";
class EvalCards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      card: null,
      people: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCards();
  }
  loadCards = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardsDataset.length; i++) {
      this.setState({
        people: this.state.people.push(cardsDataset[i].cards),
      });
    }
    console.log("poker cards " + this.state.people);
  };

  render() {
    {
      this.state.people.map((person, s) => {
        return <div key={s}>{person.cards}</div>;
      });
    }

    return <div>Helo poker</div>;
  }
}
export default EvalCards;
```

im getting  Uncaught TypeError: this.state.people.map is not a function when i run it but not sure what is wrong here any help would be great as i dont see the issue here

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `this.state.people.push()` the returned value is the new number of elements in the array, not the new array itself with the new element. So probably the property `people` changes to be an integer instead of an array, and then you can't use `map` on integer.

You need to create temporary copy of the array and then set it to `people` in `setState`.

### Option 1:

```
loadCards = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardsDataset.length; i++) {
      let newArr = this.state.people;
      newArr.push(cardsDataset[i].cards);
      this.setState({
        people: newArr,
      });
    }
    console.log("poker cards " + this.state.people);
  };
```

### Option 2:

```
loadCards = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardsDataset.length; i++) {
      this.setState({
        people: [...this.state.people , cardsDataset[i].cards],
      });
    }
    console.log("poker cards " + this.state.people);
  };
```

Comment: im trying to map the images onto array so i can display them

Comment: iam having difficulty displaying the array on screen

Comment: that's ok :) the problem is that instead of updating that array you accidentally changed it to an integer by assigning the length of the array instead of the array itself

Comment: Umm.. what do you mean by that. Are you still getting the error after the chane?

Comment: the error is gone ....but im trying to dispay the data in div but nothin is appearing on screen

Comment: Well.. I need more information about the code to help you farther with that. Like, what's in cardsDataset and cardsDataset[i].cards. Can you put it on codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import cardsDataset from "./cardsDataset";
class EvalCards extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
              super(props);
    this.state = {
      card: null,
      people: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCards();
  }
  loadCards = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardsDataset.length; i++) {
      this.setState({
        people: [...this.state.people , cardsDataset[i].cards],
    }
    console.log("poker cards " + this.state.people);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {
            this.state.people.map((person, s) => {
            return <div key={s}>{person.cards}</div>;
            });
          }
          <div>Helo poker</div>
       </div>
    )
}
export default EvalCards;


 ##you can try like that is suggested to writing  ##
```

Comment: you can try like that and it's suggested to wirting

Comment: u just copied the above answer....whats the point in copying someone else answer

Comment: I feel no good , the render function is different from you write.  i only suggest you do like that